# What does these ... mean in this example?

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php and in the following example, I don't understand `...`  prepended with the `$ints` parameter in the function definition.

```
<?php
// Coercive mode
function sumOfInts(int ...$ints)
{
    return array_sum($ints);
}

var_dump(sumOfInts(2, '3', 4.1));
```

Can anybody please tell me what those **dots** are for?

Thanks.

Comment: Search, search then search again.... then ask a question

Comment: This allows you to have variable amount of parameters http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php $ints is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that means that when you call that function, you can pass X integers and the function will process them, doesn't matter how many are they. If you call `sumOfInts(3,4,6,2,9)` or `sumOfInts(3,2,9)`, the function works, no matter how many arguments you pass